# DRY and Typing Specialization

Tags: php, php-8, liskov-substitution-principle

while I was learning PHP, I thought of a (simple?) problem that I could not solve "properly".
Here it is:

- I would like to create multiple "specialized containers"
- I would like to avoid duplicated code

For example:

```
<?php

interface BagInterface
{

    public function has(string $key) : bool;
    public function get(string $key, mixed $fallback) : mixed;
    public function set(string $key, mixed $value) : self;
    public function del(string $key) : void;
    public function all() : array;
    public function filter(callable $callback) : array;

}

abstract class AbstractBag implements BagInterface
{

    private array $bag;

    public function has(string $key) : bool
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->bag);
    }

    public function get(string $key, mixed $fallback = null) : mixed
    {
        return $this->has($key) ? $this->bag[$key] : $fallback;
    }

    public function set(string $key, mixed $value) : self
    {
        $this->bag[$key] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function del(string $key) : void
    {
        unset($this->bag[$key]);
    }

    public function all() : array
    {
        return $this->bag;
    }

    public function filter(callable $callback) : array
    {
        return array_filter($this->bag, $callback, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
    }

}
```

So, I could then create "specialized" bag:

```
<?php

class CookieBag extends AbstractBag
{

    public function get(string $key, ?Cookie $fallback = null) : ?Cookie
    {
        return parent::get($key, $fallback);
    }

    public function set(string $key, Cookie $cookie) : self
    {
        return parent::set($key, $cookie);
    }

}

class CandyBag extends AbstractBag
{

    public function get(string $key, ?Candy $fallback = null) : ?Candy
    {
        return parent::get($key, $fallback);
    }

    public function set(string $key, Candy $candy) : self
    {
        return parent::set($key, $candy);
    }

}
```

I understood that it's not possible in PHP, as it is breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle.

For example:

```
<?php

class GrandMa
{
    public function giveCookie(BagInterface $bag)
    {
        // Will be fine, BagInterface said "mixed"
        // But break LSP, error if $bag is a not a CookieBag
        bag->set('abc', new Cookie());
    }
}
```

So, I read multiple post on the same "problem", and none of them provided a clear solution, few mentioned the Observer Pattern, but I do not really see how to apply it.
Maybe I am too tired / blinded by the C++ template approach...

Does anyone have any advise, example, or better approach ?

Thanks !

Comment: I agree, I can't see how you can do this in php

Comment: If you try to "specialise" a derived class parameters then that class won't be substitutable for the base class. Since LSP test has failed then you should ask yourself: should I be using inheritance here? maybe composition would would be preferable?

Comment: @Rain Yes, I knew it was not the way, as it is just for my learning process, I do not have "real world" example, and this was the "simplest" working example I could think of to illustrate the idea (share a lot, just few typing different). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, specializing collections like this is often the example given for the usefulness of ["generic" or "templated" types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming). Rather than **extending** the base class, you would **specialise** it with a type parameter, giving something like this:

```php
class GenericBag<T>
{
    // ...

    public function get(string $key, ?T $fallback = null) : T
    {
        return $this->has($key) ? $this->bag[$key] : $fallback;
    }

    public function set(string $key, T $value) : self
    {
        $this->bag[$key] = $value;

        return $this;
    }
    
    // ...
}

class GrandMa
{
    public function giveCookie(GenericBag<Cookie> $bag)
    {
        bag->set('abc', new Cookie());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, those don't exist in PHP, and are unlikely to any time soon because there are some fundamental problems with how they would fit into the existing language.

The best you can do in the meantime is to use  some machine readable documentation which can be read by various static analysis tools and IDEs. Here for instance is [Psalm's documentation for it](https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/templated_annotations/); a lot of other tools support the same syntax.

So the above example would be:

```php
/** @template T */
class GenericBag
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param string $key
     * @param T|null $fallback
     * @return T
     */
    public function get(string $key, $fallback = null)
    {
        return $this->has($key) ? $this->bag[$key] : $fallback;
    }

   /**
     * @param string $key
     * @param T $value
     * @return GenericBag<T>
     */
    public function set(string $key, $value) : self
    {
        $this->bag[$key] = $value;

        return $this;
    }
    
    // ...
}

class GrandMa
{
    /**
      * @param GenericBag<Cookie> $bag
      */
    public function giveCookie(GenericBag $bag)
    {
        bag->set('abc', new Cookie());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@IMSoP Thanks for you answer! So now, I know there is no "template-like" way to achieve this in PHP. Your solution looks great to avoid code-duplication, but I do not like the idea of relying on "add-ons".

So, I endup with the following "solution", which seems to be more "safe" (at least for me).

```
<?php

interface BagInterface
{

    public function has(string $key) : bool;
    public function get(string $key, mixed $fallback) : mixed;
    public function set(string $key, mixed $value) : self;
    public function delete(string $key) : self;
    
    // ... Rest of Generic Functions Declarations 

}

class Bag implements BagInterface
{

    private array $items = [];

    public function has(string $key) : bool
    {
        return \array_key_exists($key, $this->items);
    }

    public function get(string $key, mixed $fallback = null) : mixed
    {
        return $this->has($key) ? $this->items[$key] : $fallback;
    }

    public function set(string $key, mixed $value) : self
    {
        $this->items[$key] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function delete(string $key) : self
    {
        unset($this->items[$key]);

        return $this;
    }

    // ... Rest of Generic Functions Definitions
    
}
```

And then, for "specialization", I have used "Adapter Pattern ?" (I tried to add some logic to make it more "realistic").

```
<?php

interface CookieBagInterface
{

    public function has(string $name) : bool;
    public function get(string $name) : ?CookieInterface;
    // Changed set(...) to add(...), because I do not need $key
    public function add(CookieInterface $cookie) : self;
    public function delete(string $name) : self;

    // ... Rest of Specialized Functions Declarations

}

class CookieBag implements CookieBagInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        private BagInterface $bag,
    )
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public function has(string $name) : bool
    {
        return $this->bag->has($name);
    }

    public function get(string $name) : ?CookieInterface
    {
        return $this->bag->get($name, null);
    }

    public function add(CookieInterface $cookie) : self
    {
        $added = \setcookie($cookie->getName(), $cookie->getValue(), [
            'expires'  => $cookie->getExpires(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
            'domain'   => $cookie->getDomain(),
            'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            'httponly' => $cookie->isHttpOnly(),
            'samesite' => $cookie->getSameSitePolicy(),
        ]);

        if ($added)
        {
            $this->bag->set($cookie->getName(), $cookie);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function delete(string $name) : self
    {
        $cookie = $this->get($name);

        if ($cookie === null)
        {
            return $this;
        }

        $removed = \setcookie($cookie->getName(), '', 1);

        if ($removed)
        {
            $this->bag->delete($name);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    // ... Rest of Specialized Functions Definitions

}
```

Benefits:

- It works
- I can modify methods (for example: Bag::set() / CookieBag::add(), do not need $key)
- I can add "logic?" to methods (for example: CookieBag::add() and CookieBag::delete() use \setcookie())

Downsides:

- I have to re-declare (interface) and re-define (class) each needed
- I have to pass my "Generic" Bag to the constructor (or should I break Dependency Inversion Principle and add `$bag = new Bag()` to the constructor?)

Thanks!